# find last editor aka author of Item in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

Ok I've used this in the past to get last editor and it works great when running on sites that use workflow but it doesnt return any users for sites that do not use workflow..

```
var contentWorkflow = contentItem.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(contentItem);
var contentHistory = contentWorkflow.GetHistory(contentItem);
if (contentHistory.Length > 0)
{                    
//submitting user (string)
string lastUser = contentHistory[contentHistory.Length - 1].User;   
}
```

Can you reply with a way to get last editor of an item regardless of whether they use workflow or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
contentItem.Statistics.UpdatedBy
```

You can check more [members of the `ItemStatistics` class here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.0/Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemStatisticsMembers.html).

Comment: This returns the fully qualified username. Is it possible to return the user's actual name instead (e.g., instead of "sitecore/jdoe," can you get "John Doe")?

Comment: Figured it out. `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(contentItem.Statistics.UpdatedBy, false).Profile.FullName`